# JPEG decompression from MemoryStream c#

Tags: c#, bitmap, jpeg, compression

In my program, I compress a BMP into a JPEG like this:

```
private void ConvertBmpToStreamJPG30(Bitmap b, Stream s)
{
  s.Flush();
  EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
  encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 30L);
  b.Save(s, GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), encoderParameters);
}
```

Then a function is receiving the JPEG in a MemoryStream, I transform it into a Bitmap by doing

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(stream);
```

When I display the image, there are a lot of lines like this :

[image: Screenshot]

What am I doing wrong, people?

**Edit 1**
Here a small visual studio solution showing the problem: http://www.fast-files.com/getfile.aspx?file=79311

It is the beginning of a screen sharing software. What it does: It takes screenshots, compare them, compress the difference and send it to another part of the program that decompress it and recompose an image with everything received. It opens a window displaying what is "sent" on the left and the recomposed image on the right.

Comment: looks like corrupt data stream - does the jpeg open correctly in other apps?

Comment: Can you produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem? If you save the stream to disk, can you open it with explorer etc?

Comment: Why Flush() before Save()? Is the position of s at the beginning of the stream?

Comment: Also, can we get the exact bitmap file which produces this artifact?

Comment: Do you know that the original BMP file does not have these problems?

Comment: Yes, I tested it by displaying the original one and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Three things come to mind:

1. Try setting a better quality than 30 and see if that helps;
2. Check your RAM (and possibly video RAM, though I doubt that GDI+ might use VGA for compression) for hardware problems;
3. I've had a [similar weird problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515995/how-to-find-out-more-about-a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi) where I loaded some JPEG file, modified it a bit, and then saved it again. That produced an exception. The solution was to make a new bitmap based on the old one and save the copy. Try that.